# Configuration step of CMake using android toolchain takes too much time

Tags: android, c++, jenkins

I am trying to build the native code for Android using CMake 2.8.12 on a build server using Jenkins. 
At configuration step, more accurate when it's "looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h" it takes too much time (aprox. 10 minutes)

On my PC this step is done in lower than 1 minute. Both of them are using Windows 7 and the same hardware configuration.

One remark: If I will use a new version of CMake like 3.x.x it's working but the code is no compilable and I have to use CMake 2.8.12 because of some dependencies. 
Do you have some points why on build server it takes so much time? 
Thank you!

Comment: Do your pc and build server use the same compiler configuration? Looking up some headers shouldn't take much time – and definitely not 10 minutes. You can create a minimal cmake project (eg. a executable with a single file and no dependencies) and check again. If this goes faster (expecting < 1 min), it's possible a project related issue.

Comment: Btw. how's your system load on the CI server when you are affected by this problem?

Comment: Set CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM to cygwin path solved the issue. Thank you @ollo